# Twitter Bootstrap Path Breaks When Not on Homepage

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

I am currently testing my website on the local server. I have issues with twitter bootstrap's path in my header view.

On my homepage this path works fine:

```
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I move to sub-page via link:

```
<a href="index.php/home_controller/getFilmDetails?id...
```

Which translates to:

```
http://localhost/www.mywebsite.co.uk/index.php/home_controller/getFilmDetails?id=114
```

Controller code:

```
$this->load->view('/header/header_home');
$this->load->view('movies_details_view',$data);
$this->load->view('footer_home');
```

Path to twitter bootstrap does not work, and I need to change the path to:

```
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

How do I make the path work on all pages?

Comment: You shouldn't be loading your views in your Model but instead your Controller.

Comment: It is controller, just made error when typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Controller do this:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->view('/header/header_home');
$this->load->view('movies_details_view',$data);
$this->load->view('footer_home');
```

Inside you header view do this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css') ?>" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Just a quick question. Is it good practice to include this kind of paths in general when using CI?

Comment: @JamesDouglas Yeah you should be using `base_url()` in these cases. Putting just the path starting with `/` like in your question will work, until you happen to change the location of the application and now your hardcoded path is relative to the root folder and not the application folder and will break. Using `base_url()` will ensure the path is correct no matter where you move the application.